# Issues with Server Logs and Server Downtime IIS .Net Core application

Tags: c#, logging, iis, iis-7.5, iis-8

I was given a dump of logs in 2 folders (so like 200 individual files from a server that I cannot access), to see what errors/exceptions were occurring
and causing server downtime/other issues?

I have tried HTTPLogParser which cannot read the files and I have LogParser 2.2 from Microsoft (old) but I have too many files to look through individually.

I have no access to the server so cannot connect anything which sucks.

Any good ideas on how to load a folder of these 2022-11-xx.log files and get some analyses done?

An example of the data in the files are:

```
G:\LogFiles\W9BVC3\u_ex20113046.log:204:2022-10-30 00:00:18 1112.23.3.12 GET /cool-website - 80 - 147.115.242.13 Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_   (http://www.pingdom.com/) - 200 0 0 0
G:\LogFiles\W9BVC3\u_ex20113046.log:982:2022-10-30 00:01:18 1112.23.3.12 GET /cool-website - 80 - 147.115.242.13 Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_   (http://www.pingdom.com/) - 200 0 0 0
G:\LogFiles\W9BVC3\u_ex20113046.log:1061:2022-10-30 00:01:31 1112.23.3.12 GET /cool-website/api/v2/status/day - 80 - 147.115.242.13     Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/105.0.0.0+Safari/517.36 
https://examplewebsite.com/cool-website/ 200 0 0 0
```

Comment: _"to see what errors/exceptions were occurring and causing server downtime/other issues?"_ - you won't find anything useful in the raw HTTP access logs ("IIS W3C" logs). You'll need the application's own logs, which may include the OS's own Application and System event-logs.

Comment: People usually import large log files to a real database like SQL Server and then perform queries. The tools you mentioned are usually just for small files. Again, tool recommendation is off topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Dai besides the HTTP logs and std_out logs where and what other ones can I get from the server?

Comment: I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.